# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp' ---> 10 scaled_data=scaler.fit_transform(final_dataset)

Tags: python, pandas

As you can see the csv and date format is same in my code.
but why I got this error. In the bottom of this post I also attached a error image link.

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not ‘Timestamp’

I have the date column in the same format as my CSV file but still got the same error.
is there any solution for this?

my Date is in the format 2018-07-20 the same as provided CSV
Could you please help me with this?

My code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize']=20,10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dropout,Dense


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df=pd.read_csv("NSE-Tata-Global-Beverages-Limited.csv")
df.head()


df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
df.index=df['Date']

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(df["Close"],label='Close Price history')


data=df.sort_index(ascending=True,axis=0)
new_dataset=pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date','Close'])

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    new_dataset["Date"][i]=data['Date'][i]
    new_dataset["Close"][i]=data["Close"][i]



scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
final_dataset=new_dataset.values

train_data=final_dataset[0:987,:]
valid_data=final_dataset[987:,:]

new_dataset.index=new_dataset.Date
new_dataset.drop("Date",axis=1,inplace=True)
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data=scaler.fit_transform(final_dataset)

x_train_data,y_train_data=[],[]

for i in range(60,len(train_data)):
    x_train_data.append(scaled_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_train_data.append(s[enter image description here][1]caled_data[i,0])
    
x_train_data,y_train_data=np.array(x_train_data),np.array(y_train_data)

x_train_data=np.reshape(x_train_data,(x_train_data.shape[0],x_train_data.shape[1],1))
```

> open this link to see error

Kindy help me to solve it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8IOQ.png
 kindly open this link to see error image

Answer (score 1):

solve my own issue
consider this section of code.

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
final_dataset=new_dataset.values

train_data=final_dataset[0:987,:]
valid_data=final_dataset[987:,:]

new_dataset.index=new_dataset.Date
new_dataset.drop("Date",axis=1,inplace=True)
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data=scaler.fit_transform(final_dataset)
```

Line 7 and 8 must be before Line 2. In below rewrite my code.

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
new_dataset.index=new_dataset.Date
new_dataset.drop(“Date”,axis=1,inplace=True)
final_dataset=new_dataset.values

train_data=final_dataset[0:987,:]
valid_data=final_dataset[987:,:]

scaled_data=scaler.fit_transform(final_dataset)
```